# Plugin Store: Page not found

Tags: craft3

I'm having a strange problem on a recent craft install. The plugin store doesn't load, and only reports "Page not found".

- I've tried another craft install on the same system, and it's working fine.
- I tried replacing all core craft files with freshly downloaded 3.0.2 files.
- I've cleared caches, ran updates, loosened all permissions to 777 and everything in between.
- I've tried two different browsers with cache cleared.
- I have only 2 plugins installed: Redactor and Position Fieldtype — but I have those on another install as well and that install is fine.
- The logs in /storage/logs don't show any errors. I tail them, and nothing is reported.

Aside from the plugin page, all other craft systems work. Even the backups can run and save locally.

Is there anything else I can try to either diagnose or solve? Feel like I've hit a wall. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There is a bug. When the setting:

```
omitScriptNameInUrls' => false,
```

is set to "false" in

```
/config/general.php
```

The Plugin Store doesn't load. Switching that setting to **true** will fix it.

Comment: Did you report this bug to support@craftcms.com?

Comment: Yup, and reported on GitHub: https://github.com/craftcms/docs/issues/110